# why does a char + another char = a weird number

Tags: java, char, string-concatenation, implicit-conversion

Here's the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[]arg) 
{
    char ca = 'a' ; 
    char cb = 'b' ; 
    System.out.println (ca + cb) ; 
}
```

The output is:

```
195
```

Why is this the case? I would think that `'a' + 'b'` would be either `"ab"` , `"12"` , or `3`.

Whats going on here?

Comment: You've already asked 6 questions since yesterday and all about some simplest things in java. Don't you think it's worth to read some book about java basics?

Comment: i am reading a book. 
is asking questions bad? 
if asking questions is bad then this website is bad. if this website is bad then theres no impitus for you to care how many questions i ask or be here in the first place. So regardless of weather or not asking questions is bad theres no impitus to care.

Comment: OP put effort in his question, giving sample code and his own thought analysis, etc. It is a newbie question, but it shows a learning process that needs to be encouraged.

Comment: Setting aside the validity of the question (and I think it's fine) - that's the silliest logical proof I've ever seen, David.  Thanks for the chuckle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`+` of two `char` is arithmetic addition, not string concatenation. You have to do something like `"" + ca + cb`, or use `String.valueOf` and `Character.toString` methods to ensure that at least one of the operands of `+` is a `String` for the operator to be string concatenation.

#### [JLS 15.18 Additive Operators](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.18)

> If the type of either operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the `+` operator must be a type that is convertible to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.

As to why you're getting 195, it's because in ASCII, `'a' = 97` and `'b' = 98`, and `97 + 98 = 195`.

---

This performs basic `int` and `char` casting.

```
 char ch = 'a';
 int i = (int) ch;   
 System.out.println(i);   // prints "97"
 ch = (char) 99;
 System.out.println(ch);  // prints "c"
```

This ignores the issue of character encoding schemes (which a beginner should not worry about... yet!).

---

As a note, Josh Bloch noted that it is rather unfortunate that `+` is overloaded for both string concatenation and integer addition ("It may have been a mistake to overload the + operator for string concatenation." -- *Java Puzzlers*, Puzzle 11: The Last Laugh). A lot of this kinds of confusion could've been easily avoided by having a different token for string concatenation.

---

#### See also

- [Is concatenating with an empty string to do a string conversion really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506474/is-concatenating-with-an-empty-string-to-do-a-string-conversion-really-that-bad)

Comment: @abelenky, use lowercase letters `'a`, 'b'` for accuracy.

Comment: David: If you open "charmap", or "Character Map" in Windows, you'll see that the characters "a" and "b" have ASCII values 97 and 98, respectively. You might want to look-up "ASCII" in Wikipedia.

Comment: is there a way to turn the ASCII numbers back into characters. like is there a method that takes 99 and returns 'c'?

Comment: @David: I gave example of basic casting.

Answer (score 3):

I don't speak Java, but 195 is 97 + 98 = the ASCII codes for `a` and `b`. So obviously, `ca` and `cb` are interpreted as their integer values, probably because of the `+` addition which does not seem to lead to a string concatenation automatically.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a String as result of the + operator you have to use type String as operands.

You should write:

```
public static void main (String[]arg) 
{
    String ca = "a" ; 
    String cb = "b" ; 
    System.out.println (ca + cb) ; 
}
```

The + operator applied on char operands behaves as the arithmetic sum.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator doesn't operate over characters like it does over strings.  What's happening here is that `a` and `b` are being cast to their integer ASCII codepoints - 97 and 98 - and then added together.