# How to append entire second array to first array in java

Tags: java, arrays, append, concatenation

I know, We can copy or append elements of array. But, I have around 100 elements in an array. Is there any other way available so I can append array to first array.

Consider I have this two arrays.

```
 String name1[]={"abc", "def", "ghi"};
 String name2[]={"jkl", "mno", "pqr"};
```

I want to append name2 array at the end of name1.

Please help me.

would be grateful for help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728476/appending-integer-array-elements-in-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80476/how-to-concatenate-two-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 3):

[Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) provides [`Arrays.concat(T[], T[], Class<T>)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ObjectArrays.html#concat(T[],%20T[],%20java.lang.Class)).

The reason for the `Class` parameter, FYI, is because generic arrays have a distinct tendency to get upcast.  If you did `Arrays.concat(Integer[], Long[])`, did you want an `Object[]` back?  Or a `Number[]`?  Guava makes you specify so there's no ambiguity...and because all of the alternatives can lead to unpredictable `ClassCastException`s at runtime.

(Disclosure: I contribute to Guava.)

Comment: Good point about upcasting... The implementation I wrote as an answer here will break only at runtime if you provide an Integer and a Long array...

Comment: Yes, that's correct; it will break.  (Conversely, Apache's `ArrayUtils` will just give you an `Object[]`, which you might be able to cast with an unsafe warning, but that _is_ unsafe: it might lead to unpredictable `ClassCastException`s _later_.)

Comment: Added a warning in my answer. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to create a new array.

An easy implementation using generics and not using any external library:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String [] a1 = { "a", "b" };
    String [] a2 = { "c", "d", "e", "f" };

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(append(a1, a2)));
}

public <K> K[] append(K[] a1, K[] a2) {
    K[] a1a2 = Arrays.copyOf(a1, a1.length + a2.length);
    for (int i = a1.length; i < a1a2.length; i++) {
        a1a2[i] = a2[i - a1.length];
    }
    return a1a2;
}
```

OBS: As Louis Wasserman comments in his answer, Java will upcast the arrays, which can be a problem. For example, if you provide a Long[] and an Integer[] to the append method above, it will compile but you will get a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` at run-time!!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a new array. Because the length of arrays is fixed.

```
 String[] list = new String[name1.length+name2.length]
```

You could loop around the two arrays and add each element to the new array

You could also use apache commons lang library

```
 String[] both = ArrayUtils.addAll(first, second);
```

Comment: I just checked, but ArrayUtils returns Object[] not String array...Please correct me, If I am going wrong.

Comment: I might be wrong. But arrays can be casted. (Just be careful with this)

Comment: Be very careful with the casted array -- it won't behave quite like a normal `String[]`.