# transfer an int [] to a numeric series

Tags: java, arrays

How is it possible in java to have an int array and add all values from the array to a numerical series.

For example:

```
int[] num= new int[9];
for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
num[i] = i;
}
```

and I need one integer variable like:

```
int a = 12345678910
```

copied from the array.

thx a lot in advance!

Comment: Look into below thread :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674707/how-to-concatenate-int-values-in-java

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You are declaring array that can have `9` elements but in `for` loop you are trying to put to array value at index greater than max index of array. Also `12345678910` cant be integer since max integer is `2147483647`. It seems that this is [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/186652) so maybe tell us what would be purpose of this value. Maybe you should use `String` or `BigInteger` instead `int`?

Comment: @Praveen : That question is about concatenating integer digits to a String.

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It works perfectly with the StringBuilder and a long variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code which you'll need to fix first:

- your array index is bigger than the size of the array (11 > 9)
- the number you're assigning to 'a' is too big for the integer type

You could try this as a solution:

```
    StringBuilder numbers = new StringBuilder();

    int[] num = new int[9];
    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        num[i] = i;

        numbers.append(i);
    }

    long a = Long.valueOf(numbers.toString());

    System.out.println(a);
```

Note that you'll still need to check that the final output of 'numbers' is not too big for a long. If it is you'll need to use a data type that can accommodate the resulting value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems most natural to use the `StringBuilder` class, as this handles your appending 2 digit numbers most easily:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    sb.append(i);
}

int a = Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
String aStr = "";
int[] num= new int[9];
for(int i=0; i<11; i++) {
aStr = aStr + num[i];
}

a = new Integer(aStr);
```