# Trouble printing java array index values

Tags: java, arrays, println

In Java, I am printing out a simple list of values using an array.  What am I doing wrong here in my print command?

```
public class BasicArrayTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n[] = new int[10];
        n[0] = 11;
        n[1] = 23;
        n[2] = 37;
        n[3] = 41;
        n[4] = 57;
        n[5] = 60;
        n[6] = 74;
        n[7] = 85;
        n[8] = 96;
        n[9] = 10;
        System.out.println("The uneven index values are ");
        System.out.println(n[1] , n[3] , n[5] , n[7] , n[9]);
        System.out.println("The even index values are ");
        System.out.println(n[0] , n[2] , n[4] , n[6] , n[8]);

    }    
}
```

Comment: n[i] + "," + n[i+2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the integers to strings and concatenate them. This is all done with `+`.

```
System.out.println("The uneven index values are " + n[1] + ", " + n[3] + ", etc.");
```

In general though, you may want to use a [StringBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674707/how-to-concatenate-int-values-in-java).

Answer (score 1):

You are putting ',' in sysout which is not proper :

Use below way :

```
System.out.println(n[1] +","+ n[3] +","+ n[5] +","+ n[7] +","+ n[9]);
```

Comment: If I am correct, the first operand must be a string, so that `"" + ` must be added before `n[1]`.