# How to place number next to another number

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

My homework for a Java is making a GUI calculator in Java. I am in the planning of the program process and wondering how can you add a number next to another number and make it a single integer. I know there is probably a name for this but i cant remember it or i just don't know it.

`if x = 1,
and y = 2,
then z should equal 12`

How do i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like this : `z = Integer.parseInt(x+""+y);`

Comment: I would call it *concatenation*.

Comment: @javasux was any of answers helpful? If so, consider marking it as correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate or near-duplicate of [How to concatenate int values in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674707/how-to-concatenate-int-values-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

int z = Integer.parseInt(x+""+y) is the correct approach. If we need to take a negative number in the calculator application, the -ve sign will be before the first digit entered, which works well here. Also in Calculator only one digit will be added at one time, so this approach works for negative numbers as well.

Comment: Isn't that a repetition of my answer?

Comment: @Andronicus It includes more explanation (which is a very good ting). On the other hand is partially wrong about the negative sign (unary minus): it will work well if `x` is negative, but not if `y` is.

Comment: Yes it will fail if y is -ve but in the calculator when entering one number it will be a unary +ve or -ve number where only x can be -ve not any other digit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    String answer = x + "" + y;
    int z = Integer.parseInt(answer);

    System.out.println(z); //Should print 12
```