# get value from a string array where each string contains a value get the value

Tags: java

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int A=5 ;
        String str = "A"+"A";
        System.out.println(str);

    }
}
```

The output is : `AA`

but i want the output as: `55`
can any one suggest how to do?

Comment: `int A` is a variable declaration.`"A"+"A"` is the value of your variable `String str`. Completely different things. Try to change str to: `String str = ""+A+A;`

Comment: `"A"` and `A` are different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to concatenate int values in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2674707/how-to-concatenate-int-values-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage implicit coercion to string from int when you join the `int` variables with an empty `String` :

```
int A=5 ;
String str = A + "" + A;
System.out.println(str);
```

Just remove the quotes from `A` and append the variable `A` with an empty string that will prompt the Java compiler to translate the expression to `String.valueOf(A) + "" + String.valueOf(A)` implicitly and convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

[How to format strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431933/how-to-format-strings-in-java)

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int A = 5;
    String str = String.format("%s%s", A, A);
    System.out.println(str);
  }
```