# How does the String class override the + operator?

Tags: java, string, object

Why in Java you're able to add Strings with the + operator, when String is a class?  In the`String.java` code I did not find any implementation for this operator. Does this concept violate object orientation?

Comment: Plus (`+`) operator is language feature of Java.

Comment: It's all compiler's magic. You can't do operator overloading in Java.

Comment: I think the weird thing is that String is implemented as a library *outside* the language (in java.lang.String), yet it has specific support *inside* the language.  That ain't right.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does + operator behaves differently with numbers and strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955640/how-does-operator-behaves-differently-with-numbers-and-strings-in-java)

Comment: @13ren you are wrong. String is apart of the java.lang class which stands for language - the java lanaguage!!! All classes in this package is special. Notice you dont need to import java.lang to use them.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Let's look at the following simple expressions in Java

```
int x=15;
String temp="x = "+x;
```

The compiler converts `"x = "+x;` into a `StringBuilder` internally and uses `.append(int)` to "add" the integer to the string.

**[5.1.11. String Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)**

> Any type may be converted to type String by string conversion.
>
> A value x of primitive type T is first converted to a reference value
>   as if by giving it as an argument to an appropriate class instance
>   creation expression (§15.9):
>
> - If T is boolean, then use new Boolean(x).
> - If T is char, then use new Character(x).
> - If T is byte, short, or int, then use new Integer(x).
> - If T is long, then use new Long(x).
> - If T is float, then use new Float(x).
> - If T is double, then use new Double(x).
>
> This reference value is then converted to type String by string
>   conversion.
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> - If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four    ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
> - Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the    toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but
>     if    the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the
>     string    "null" is used instead.
>
> <sup>The toString method is defined by the primordial class Object
>   (§4.3.2). Many classes override it, notably Boolean, Character,
>   Integer, Long, Float, Double, and String.</sup>
>
> See §5.4 for details of the string conversion context.

**[15.18.1.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)**

> **Optimization of String Concatenation :**
>   An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation
>   in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate
>   String object. To increase the performance of repeated string
>   concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a
>   similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects
>   that are created by evaluation of an expression.
>
> For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the
>   creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a primitive
>   type to a string.

The optimized version will not actually do a full wrapped String conversion first.

This is a good illustration of an optimized version used by the compiler, albeit without the conversion of a primitive, where you can see the compiler changing things into a StringBuilder in the background:

http://caprazzi.net/posts/java-bytecode-string-concatenation-and-stringbuilder/

---

This java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cip = "cip";
    String ciop = "ciop";
    String plus = cip + ciop;
    String build = new StringBuilder(cip).append(ciop).toString();
}
```

Generates this - see how the two concatenation styles lead to the very same bytecode:

```
 L0
    LINENUMBER 23 L0
    LDC "cip"
    ASTORE 1
   L1
    LINENUMBER 24 L1
    LDC "ciop"
    ASTORE 2

   // cip + ciop

   L2
    LINENUMBER 25 L2

    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESTATIC java/lang/String.valueOf(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    ASTORE 3

    // new StringBuilder(cip).append(ciop).toString()

   L3
    LINENUMBER 26 L3

    NEW java/lang/StringBuilder
    DUP
    ALOAD 1
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/StringBuilder.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    ALOAD 2
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/StringBuilder.toString()Ljava/lang/String;

    ASTORE 4
   L4
    LINENUMBER 27 L4
    RETURN
```

Looking at the example above and how the byte code based on the source code in the given example is generated, you will be able to notice that the compiler has internally transformed the following statement

```
cip+ciop;
```

into

```
new StringBuilder(cip).append(ciop).toString();
```

In other words, the operator `+` in string concatenation is effectively a shorthand for the more verbose `StringBuilder` idiom.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I'm not familiar with jvm byte codes but generated code for
String plus = cip + ciop; and 
String build = new StringBuilder(cip).append(ciop).toString();
are same. and my question is that is this operation violates object orientation?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Operator overloading (as in C++ and some languages) has some drawbacks and Java designers felt that it's somewhat a confusing concept and omitted it from Java. To me, an object- oriented language must have the prime concepts of inheritance, Polymorphism and encapsulation that Java has.

Comment: yes, but I think that this operator has overloaded for String class

Comment: Yes, *operator overloading* is used in Java for the concatenation of the String type however, you cannot define your own operator (as in C++, C# and some other languages).

Comment: @Pooya: actually "int / int" vs. "int / float" is *already* operator overloading, so even C has that. What C (and Java) however *don't* have is user-defined operator overloading: the only thing that defines the different ways an operator can be used (in both C and Java) is the language definition (and the distinction is implemented in the compiler). C++ differs in that it allows user-defined operator overloading (which is often referred to as simply "operator overloading").

Comment: If you want overloading in java I suggest groovy the syntax is identical, it compiles to .class files and interacts very well.  You can generally just rename .java to .groovy and it will still work just like it did, but then you can use more syntax.

Comment: @Lion One small correction to your comment- in C# you can overload existing operators, but you cannot define your own new operators.

Comment: @MgSam:) Thanks for that correction. I'm less familiar with C# (or C++) than Java, sorry.

Comment: @Lion Please, how did you learn that putting ``The toString method is defined by the primordial class Object (§4.3.2). Many classes override it,.......See §5.4 for details of the string conversion context.`` between ``<sup>`` and ``</sup>`` is the way to make this portion of text appear in more little characters ? - I read the Markdown Editing help, the advanced help, and even the official Markdown syntax reference page, but I didn't find any allusion to this way of formatting.

Comment: @eyquem : Although it's not mentioned in the help, generally allowing some formatting tags like `<sup>`, `<sub>`, `<b>`, `<i>`, `<br/>`, `<s>` etc doesn't cause any security harm like XSS attacks and in general they are allowed by a text editor. I just gave it a try, when I stared questions/answers on this site and they worked. I went nowhere to see whether they are allowed by this text editor or not, just once tried them and found that they were allowed. ha ha ha... :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think that ``<sup> </sup>`` were HTML tags. In fact in the advanced help, in the **Inline HTML** section, we can read : ``If you need to do something that Markdown can't handle, use HTML.`` I wasn't as much astute as you. ah ah ah... :)

Answer (score 26):

It is Java compiler feature which checks the operands of `+` operator. And based on the operands it generates the byte code:

- For String, it generates code to concat strings
- For Numbers, it generates code to add numbers.

**This is what the Java spec says**:

> The operators + and `-` are called the additive operators.
>       AdditiveExpression:
>           MultiplicativeExpression
>           AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression
>           AdditiveExpression - MultiplicativeExpression
>
> The additive operators have the same precedence and are syntactically 
>       left associative (they group left-to-right). **If the type of either 
>       operand of a `+` operator is `String`, then the operation is string concatenation.**
>
> Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the `+` operator must be a type that 
>       is convertible (§5.1.8)to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> In every case, the type of each of the operands of the binary `-` operator must be
>       a type that is convertible (§5.1.8) to a primitive numeric type, or a 
>       compile-time error occurs.

Comment: The quote from the spec isn't relevant to this question at all.

Comment: This is the extract "If the type of either operand of a + operator is String, then the operation is string concatenation.

Otherwise, the type of each of the operands of the + operator must be a type that is convertible (§5.1.8)to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs". Can you please tell me why it is not relevant.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about how it's implemented, which is the question. I think the poster already understand that the feature exists.

Answer (score 14):

> How String class overrides + operator?

It doesn't. The compiler does it. Strictly speaking, the compiler *overloads* the + operator for String operands.

Answer (score 6):

First of all (+) is overloaded not overridden

> The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator (+), which has been overloaded for Java Strings
>   objects.

1. If left hand side operand is String it works as concatenation.
2. If left hand side operand is Integer it works as addition operator

Comment: (2) If the left operand is an Integer it is auto-unboxed to `int` and then the normal rules of Java apply.

Comment: The two rules given below the quote are wrong: I believe they should be: two primitives (or unboxable classes) = addition; at least one string = concatenation

Answer (score 4):

The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator (+) and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the `StringBuilder`(or `StringBuffer`) class and its `append` method.

Answer (score 4):

The meaning of the `+` operator when applied to `String` is defined by the language, as everyone has written already. Since you don't seem to find this sufficiently convincing, consider this:

Ints, floats and doubles all have different binary representations, and therefore adding two ints is a different operation, in terms of bit manipulation, than adding two floats: For ints you can add bit by bit, carrying a bit and checking for overflow; for floats you must deal with the mantissas and exponents separately.

So, in principle, "addition" depends on the nature of the objects being "added". Java defines it for Strings as well as ints and floats (longs, doubles, ...)

Answer (score 3):

The `+` operator is usually replaced by a `StringBuilder` at compile time. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4648607/stringbuilder-stringbuffer-vs-operator) for more details on that matter.

Comment: If this is the case, is there any reason why StringBuilder exists at all for public use ? Are there any cases where `+` operator is not replaced by `StringBuilder` ?

Comment: The question you want to ask is "why does the + operator exist at all for public use?", because thats the abomination here. As for your other question, I do not know it exactly, but I'd guess there is no such case.

Comment: Compiler might use concat() instead, if there are just two elements. Also compiler fails to replace concat() with StringBuilder( or uses multiple StringBuilders and appends them together) when programmer is building string in long nested/looped code - using single, explicit StringBuilder will be better for performance.