# String object in java

Tags: java, string, object, immutability

As we know `String` is immutable, which means a new instance is created every time.

My question is that if I write:

```
System.out.println("Java"+"is"+"programming");
```

then how many objects are created in pool?

Comment: When this code is compiled, it gets converted into a single string object. Try decompiling this code to see this.

Comment: `which means a new instance is created every time` this is not true

Answer (score 0):

Your example will create a single string object in the string pool.

after that, if you do:

```
String x = "Javaisprogramming";
```

it will still point to the same object in the string pool. You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801343/what-is-string-pool-in-java)

Answer (score -1):

Your example will create a single string object. This is noted [throughout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html) the [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html) [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html).

The way I understand it, Java only adds new strings to the string pool when they're initially created. So,

```
String str1 = "hello";
```

Would be a single string in the pool.

So would

```
String str2 = "Java" + "is" + "cool";
```

Comment: Is this object create in string pool or out side of string pool,

Answer (score -1):

Your Example will create 'single' string only which is

```
String x = "Javaisprogramming";
```

because '+' is a string concatenation operator in java(it internally call append()) so when you call `System.out.println("Java"+"is"+"programming");` then compiler create one string object from concatenation and send it with `println()` method.

for more about '+' operator see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408427/how-does-the-string-class-override-the-operator)