# Why does comparing strings with the same value with == return false?

Tags: java, string, equals, equality

In the following code a string is created in pool and then it is concat creating there additional string object. The final is "2cfalse" and is referred by a. Then in line 7, because of Strings' non-repeating nature, I think it does not create separate literal as "2cfalse" so the == operator must return true .. Why its not returning true..

```
class demo {
    public static void main(String aaa[]) {
        String a = "";
        a += 2;
        a += 'c';
        a += false;
        if (a == "2cfalse")
            System.out.println(1);
        if (a.equals("2cfalse"))
            System.out.println(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: The compiler will for `+=` (or smiply `+`) on Strings create a StringBuilder behind the scene, and use its `.append()`-method ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11408526/1682559)). So with every `+=` you actually create a new String-object that also need to be garbage collected. Which is why we got classes like `StringBuilder` for appending Strings. So in your check `if (a == "2cfalse")` they aren't referencing to the same String-object.

Comment: Your code a += 2 is equivalent to String s = new StringBuffer().append(a).append("2"),  So you have to s.intern() in order for == to work,  your question is probably linked to wrong question

Comment: Thank you guys. this is the answer i was expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `==` compares `String`s by *their memory location* vs `String.equals` which compares them *lexicographically*.