# in java while working on eclipse IDE,

Tags: java

When I do the first code I'm getting the following output (whereas it is expected to be something else). Now with a small change the result is different. Why is that?

**CASE 1**

```
package mydemo;

public class hw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
        int x =10;
        int y =20;
        int result = x + y;
        System.out.println(" result");


    }

}
```

output:

```
HelloWorld
 result
```

**CASE 2**

```
package mydemo;

public class hw {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("HelloWorld");
        int x =10;
        int y =20;
        int result = x + y;
        System.out.println(" result = " + result);


    }

}
```

output

```
HelloWorld
 result = 30
```

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: Why would you think that it would print out the value of the variable `result` if you don't tell it to? We may be able to help you more if you tell us the expected output.

Comment: What did you expect?

Comment: `"result"` and `result` are to different thing, the first is a String representation of the word _result_  the seconds is a variable name. So basicly, you resolved your problem off _How to print the value of a variable_ yourself by telling Java to print the variable and not just a constant String.

Comment: you need to read the book "complete reference java" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference in your two cases, is the parameter passed to you "**println**" function:

**In CASE1:**

```
System.out.println(" result");
```

Here the parameter **" result"** (double quote should not be omited) is a string literal. It represents the word itself you typed between the **double quote** symbol and do not related with the int variable **result** you have defined in the previous line.

Thus when you call **prinln**, the function received an String variable and print to the console as it is.

**In CASE2:**

```
System.out.println(" result = " + result);
```

And in the above case, however, you passed an expression `"result = " + result` to the **println** function, in your case, which is a **String** "plus" an **int** variable operation. Java compiler will firstly convert your expression `" result = " + result` into a String `" result = 30"` and then pass it to the **println** function.

What the compiler do to the above expression is just like replacing it with the following code:

```
new StringBuilder(" result = ").append(result).toString();
```

Which will generate some kind of java bytecode like the following:

```
12: invokespecial #26                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
15: iload_1       
16: invokevirtual #29                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
19: invokevirtual #33                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Also find this answer useful if you have interest in how the compiler dealing with the expression:

[How does the String class override the + operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408427/how-does-the-string-class-override-the-operator)

Answer (score 0):

When you tell it to:

```
System.out.println(" result");
```

it prints the stuff in the parentheses, which is " result". The quotation marks around the word "result" means that it is a string literal. So the output is

```
 result
```

In the second case, this is in the parentheses:

```
" result = " + result
```

As you can see, we still have a string literal - " result = ". You see the `+` character over there? That thing connects thing. So here, it connects " result = " with `result`. What is `result`? Since it has no quotes around itself, it is not a string literal. Here, `result` refers to the value of the variable called `result`. What is the value? 30!

So that's why it prints:

```
 result = 30
```